# print each item in a stack without removing it

Tags: python

Is it possible to peek into other parts of the stack without removing items from the stack? I want to print each layer but `s.peek` only shows the top layer of the stack.

```
s=Stack()
#items in the stack
s.push("Adam")
s.push("Ben")
s.push("Cassie")
s.push("Deborah")
s.push("Elvin")
```

Comment: Did you write the `Stack` class? Where is it coming from?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation of `Stack`.
However, Python lists are great to be used as stacks, with their `append` and `pop` methods:

```
>>> stack = []
>>> stack.append(1)
>>> stack.append(2)
>>> stack.append(3)
>>> stack
[1, 2, 3]
>>> stack.pop()
3
>>> stack
[1, 2]
```

The nice bonus is that you can still use it as a list, especially for iteration:

```
>>> for elt in stack:
...     print(elt)
...
1
2
```

Of course, you might not like the `append` name, that does not really reflect the essence of a stack.
If you want a clean interface, you can extend the `list` class, so as to define a `push` method that aliases `append`, a `peek` method that only returns the last element pushed, and you can even redefine the iteration behaviour, so as to naturally iterate from the top.

```
class Stack(list):
    def push(self, elt):
        self.append(elt)

    def peek(self):
        return self[-1]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(reversed(self))
```

Comment: You should also note that `peek` can simply be performed with `stack[-1]`.

Comment: Or `Stack.push = Stack.append`